# My configuration of firebase_admin is good to authenticate users?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to verify the token id my code its working, but why is working? i setup good?

i have that doubt because auth variable does not know the credentials to verify the token, the variable who know the credentials is `firebase_app`, how auth variable is verifying the token?

```
from firebase_admin import auth
from django.conf import settings

fire_credentials = credentials.Certificate(FIREBASE_CONFIG_credentials)
fire_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(fire_credentials)


def login():
    token = 'eyJhbGciO...'
    try:
       auth.verify_id_token(token)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Auth comes from firebase_admin:

```
from firebase_admin import auth
```

When you initialize firebase_admin:

```
firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(firebase_creds)
```

you are also initializing all of its components.

If your calls are not returning any errors, then everything is OK.